# Will Linux kernel support distributed threads across multi-computer in cluster?

Tags: linux, multithreading, cluster-computing

I have an immature idea, if kernel can assign threads in a process to different computers in cluster, we can view so much computers as one computer. That is, the kernel can support cluster originally. Certainly we should configure cluster nodes into kernel.
or, is there user-space app can support this functionality?

Comment: This is a well known technique called a "single system image", and was implemented on Linux by MOSIX and later openMosix. You can read about these projects to find out why no one does it anymore.

Comment: thanks, I learned it.

Comment: the concept of thread assumes they access common memory. Access memory on another computer is prohibitively expensive. If we forbid access to memory in another computer, thread becomes a single-threaded process, as it already was at early days of Unix.